# Retrieving detailed photo info

Tags: iphone

Is there photo information that can tell you if a photo from your library was sent as a multimedia message? i have tried iphone applications but they only give basis information.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46265/date-original-picture-was-taken-using-exif-wizard) is a good explanation of the relationship between EXIF data, MMS, and the Photo Library. Basically, MMS does not add EXIF data to the photo, but the iPhone, once it receives the photo, adds its own EXIF data, including the current date and time.

So, long story short, there is no specific data field that conveys whether or not a photo was sent via MMS.